# when I run React Native app it's give me error [> Failed to install the following SDK components Android SDK Platform 31]

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, runtime-error

**Error**

```
`error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to install the following SDK components:
      platforms;android-31 Android SDK Platform 31
  Install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s

    at makeError (C:\Users\dp312\Desktop\Project\AwesomeProject\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\dp312\Desktop\Project\AwesomeProject\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\dp312\Desktop\Project\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\dp312\Desktop\Project\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

[**here is Error Img**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nnvsf.png)

or when I set sdk platform tool it's give me like this error or it's not install and also my emulator also not install I don't know why here is error img

[**android sdk error**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS3nP.png)

**Error**

```
An error occurred while preparing SDK package CMake 3.18.1: Tag mismatch!.
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Platform 32: Tag mismatch!.
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Platform 29: Tag mismatch!.
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image: Tag mismatch!.
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image: Tag mismatch!.
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Build-Tools 31: Tag mismatch!.
An error occurred while preparing SDK package NDK (Side by side) 21.4.7075529: Tag mismatch!.
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image: Tag mismatch!.
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Platform 31: Tag mismatch!.
An error occurred while preparing SDK package NDK (Side by side) 20.1.5948944: Tag mismatch!.
```

I just create project and run it without edit app.js file but it's also give error. above I give
how can I soul this error, and where I'm doing mistake?

I'm so confuse about it

Comment: Have you installed `Android SDK Platform 31` and system image from Android Studio's SDK platforms? The [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) provides more details on it.

Comment: yes when I install Android SDK platform 31 its give me like this [android sdk error]img above I give

Comment: when I install 31 sdk its give me [
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 31 (revision: 1)".
Downloading http://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-31_r01.zip
This download could not be finalized from the interim state. Retrying without caching.
Downloading http://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-31_r01.zip
Failed packages:
- Android SDK Platform 31 (platforms;android-31)]